# Calling player stats from vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

Okay, so I have a player name vector within a class as well as a functioning register and login system that reads from files. (Ex: Allura.txt, or Bob.txt).
Usernames and passwords are saved seperated by a ";", which I use as a delimiter with the getline function:

```
getline(ReadFile, filename, ';');
getline(ReadFile, filepass, ';');
```

Now I'm stuck. I've created a command for whenever a player enters 'stats'.
What is the best solution for C++ to know which player is typing stats, and to print those statistics of that player from the vector without prompting the player to define their name to search through the vector every time? I could use temporary variables but if more than one player enters stats, that variable will be overwritten to the next player. I will explain more clearly if needed; I've been confused with this for days.

Comment: Main:

http://pastebin.com/61WkGFuM

Character.h Class File:

http://pastebin.com/v0Aa4hrz

Character.cpp Source File:

http://pastebin.com/y7HWZ9cY

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want your UI to be some kind of Finite State Machine (FSM). You'd have two states at this point: Logged Out and Logged In.

When the user successfully runs the "login" command, the UI records which user is logged in, and goes to a state where the "stats" command is available. "stats" can then use the stored username to show that user's stats.

Here's a great guide to FSM design: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html

Comment: Thanks. Very complicated from here. The program now detects whether the player has logged in to use the stats command, but if I have more than one player name in the vector, there's still no way to detect which player entered the stats command. Don't understand how games know which player is which when using containers..